# Why is this error in parameterized constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, compilation

alright , heres the code :

```
public class MyClass {

long var;
public void MyClass(long param)
{
var=param; //st1
}

public static void main(string args[])
{
MyClass a,b;
a=new MyClass(); //st2
b=new MyClass(5); //st3
}

}
```

why error occurs at st3 instead of line st2 ?

Comment: I think there is no void or return type in constructor. If you remove that try in IDE you can easily find answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
public void MyClass(long param)
```

declares a *method* called `MyClass`, whereas I suspect you wanted a constructor. Remove the return type:

```
public MyClass(long param)
```

At that point I suspect you'll get the behaviour you expect.

Personally I think it's a design flaw that Java *allows* you to declare a method with the same name as the containing type, but that's a different matter.

Also note that

```
main(string args[])
```

should be

```
main(String args[])
```

or more conventionally:

```
main(String[] args)
```

Comment: I think OP want more of no default constructor issue.

Comment: @Nambari: You can call a constructor with a `long` parameter with an `int` argument, because there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `long`.

Comment: @Nambari: Well as soon as a constructor *has* been supplied, there'll be no parameterless constructor... which is basically what my answer is about.

Comment: I am not saying your answer is wrong, just comment that OP requirement may be different.

Comment: @Nambari: I really don't think the OP's requirement is different. The OP was expecting his method to be a constructor, and therefore there not to be a parameterless constructor. I don't see what my answer doesn't address there.

Comment: but theres no return type for the constructor :X .

Comment: @AjZ: There is in the code you posted - you've declared that it returns `void`. Because you've specified that, it's *not* a constructor - it's a method.

Comment: @AjZ: Why do you need to close it? Haven't I *answered* your question? Just hit the accept button (the tickmark) if you're happy with the answer - not that you *need* to do that, of course (it's purely optional).